# How to enable Bountysource plugin on GitHub to have integration with issues?

Tags: github, bountysource

I have Authorized app (Bountysource) at /settings/applications on GitHub (by linking my account into GitHub).

Now I would like to have interactive integration with GitHub issues (so it'll automatically add the bounties into the footer), for example:

> Want to back this issue? Post a bounty on it! We accept bounties via Bountysource.
>
> There is a **$10 open bounty** on this issue. Add to the bounty at Bountysource.

as seen in [here](https://github.com/bountysource/frontend/issues/978), [here](https://github.com/bountysource/frontend/issues/153) and [here](https://github.com/OpenRA/OpenRA/issues/9261).

Any idea how to add that? Is it done by app or maybe some [web-browser plugin](https://github.com/bountysource/browser-extension)? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be found in Home/Tools (GitHub Committer Tools) at /tools on [Bountysource site](https://www.bountysource.com/).

From there you can choose the option to Modify issue titles and bodies as shown below:

[image: Bountysource GitHub Committer Tools]

Comment: That only works if you're part of the organization, right? If I'm a random user needing an issue fixed, it looks like I need to [manually post the Markdown code in a comment on the issue](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84152/how-to-enable-bountysource-plugin-on-github-to-have-integration-with-issues/84915#84915).

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with permissions, you can use code like this in issue
body instead:

```
<bountysource-plugin>
[![Bountysource][1]][2]
[1]:http://bountysource.com/badge/issue?issue_id=4807368
[2]:http://bountysource.com/issues/4807368-support-for-package-upgrade
</bountysource-plugin>
```

Comment: @DanDascalescu its always done that, and if you use the code they propose, you get duplicate buttons on the bountysource page

Comment: where did my older comments go? It appears you're replying to me out of the blue. Did you flag them? Also, could you post a screenshot with the duplicate buttons from [this bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/8351500-cinnamon-should-support-hotkeys-window-shortcuts-for-selecting-existing-windows)? Is one at the very top, and one in the actual comment that includes the badge? Aside from the `<bountysource-plugin>` line, they also have a different URL for the image, `api.`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a member of the project but want to offer a bounty, BountySource offers code, including Markdown, that you can manually post on the issue. To get the code, click on the badge:

[image: It's not obvious that you can click on the badge to get the code]

The Markdown is in the following format:

```
[![Bountysource](https://api.bountysource.com/badge/issue?issue_id=35788114)](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/35788114-retain-the-line-column-position-for-recent-files)
```